# Why i'm getting null exception when trying to GetComponent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Both scripts are attached to the same empty GameObject in the hierarchy.
First the SpawnObjects script is attached then the MoveObjects.

This is the script with the exception.
The exception is on the line:

```
mover.minXPos = minXPos;
```

The exception message:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SpawnObjects.RandomSpawn () (at Assets/MyScripts/SpawnObjects.cs:28)
SpawnObjects.Start () (at Assets/MyScripts/SpawnObjects.cs:18)
```

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnObjects : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject PrefabToSpawn;
    public int MaximumObjects = 100;
    public int minXPos = -1000;
    public int maxXPos = 1000;
    public int minYPos = 50;
    public int maxYPos = 150;
    public int minZPos = -1000;
    public int maxZPos = 1000;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        RandomSpawn();
    }

    private void RandomSpawn()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < MaximumObjects; i++)
        {
            Vector3 spawnLocation = new Vector3(Random.Range(minXPos, maxXPos), Random.Range(minYPos, maxYPos), Random.Range(minZPos, maxZPos));
            GameObject spawned = (GameObject)Instantiate(PrefabToSpawn, spawnLocation, Quaternion.identity);
            MoveObjects mover = spawned.GetComponent<MoveObjects>();
            mover.minXPos = minXPos;
            mover.maxXPos = maxXPos;
            mover.minYPos = minYPos;
            mover.maxYPos = maxYPos;
            mover.minZPos = minZPos;
            mover.maxZPos = maxZPos;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the script of the MoveObjects

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveObjects : MonoBehaviour {

    public int minXPos = -1000;
    public int maxXPos = 1000;
    public int minYPos = 50;
    public int maxYPos = 150;
    public int minZPos = -1000;
    public int maxZPos = 1000;
    public float speed = 30;

    private Vector3 destinationLocation;

    private float midX;
    private float midY;
    private float midZ;

    void Start()
    {
        midX = (minXPos + maxXPos) / 2;
        midY = (minYPos + maxYPos) / 2;
        midZ = (minYPos + maxYPos) / 2;
        GenerateNewDestinationPoint();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        if (ArrivedAtLocation())
            GenerateNewDestinationPoint();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        transform.LookAt(destinationLocation);
        transform.Translate(transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private bool ArrivedAtLocation()
    {
        return (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, destinationLocation) < 1);
    }

    private void GenerateNewDestinationPoint()
    {
        float newX = (transform.position.x < midX) ? Random.Range(midX, maxXPos) : Random.Range(minXPos, midX);
        float newY = (transform.position.y < midY) ? Random.Range(midY, maxYPos) : Random.Range(minYPos, midY);
        float newZ = (transform.position.z < midZ) ? Random.Range(midZ, maxZPos) : Random.Range(minZPos, midZ);

        destinationLocation = new Vector3(newX, newY, newZ);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the C tag??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a possibility that your spawned object doesn't have the component attached that you are trying to access. So its always safe to check for null before using it.

```
    MoveObjects mover = spawned.GetComponent<MoveObjects>();
    if(mover == null)
    {
        // your prefab doesn't have the component attached. maybe add it.
        mover = spawned.AddComponent<MoveObject>();
    }
    mover.minXPos = minXPos;
    mover.maxXPos = maxXPos;
    mover.minYPos = minYPos;
    mover.maxYPos = maxYPos;
    mover.minZPos = minZPos;
    mover.maxZPos = maxZPos;
```